# How to use octokat.js with webpack in the browser?

Tags: javascript, github-api, octokat.js

I am trying to use [octokat.js](https://github.com/philschatz/octokat.js) in a web app but the library tries to load XMLHttpRequest for Node which is a bad idea in the browser.

The problem comes from a `require` in octokat code that is handled by webpack when it should be ignored. [Code here](https://github.com/philschatz/octokat.js/blob/master/src/request.coffee#L21).

How am I supposed to install and use octokat.js to use with webpack ?

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question, I realise that using webpack externals seems to work:

```
// webpack.config.js
, externals: { xmlhttprequest: "XMLHttpRequest" }
```

Is there another (better) way to handle this ?